# Splitting an Arraylist in a table using a Foreach Loop in JSP

Tags: jsp, arraylist, foreach, jstl, jsp-tags

Here's the catch, I have an arrayList within a foreach loop in a jsp page shown below. So, I wanted to have 3 columns having 3 rows each which has continuous values. How am I suppose to apply this scenario in the simplest way?

To clarify:

```
Column1      Column2      Column3
 Data1        Data4        Data7
 Data2        Data5        Data8
 Data3        Data6        Data9


<table>
<c:set var="numCols" value="3"/>
<c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="info" varStatus = "status"> 
   <c:if test="${status.index % numCols == 0}">
    <tr>
    </c:if>
        <td><input type ="submit" class="data btnColor" 
                   value="${info.dataName}" label ="${info.dataId}" />
        </td>
        <c:if test="${status.count % numCols == 0 or status.last}">
    </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: anyone there? please help!

Comment: You need to update your code that you are trying to run. Your code above has not changed. I can't help you with why it is not running until I see what you are trying to run.

Comment: @Shaggy125 pls help me with this, how can I set the limit of 3 in the rows?

Comment: Sorry for the upset hope you understand

Comment: @Shaggy125 Sir, can u write the purpose of each significant line of code for documentation purposes?

Comment: I've update the code with comments this time since I see that you are new to SO.  However, in the future, you need to put a bit more work into these questions.  Do some research on your own.  If there is still something you don't understand, either start a new question or be specific about exactly what it is you don't understand.  i.e. "In your code you have an if block that says this ..., from my understanding that means this ..., is that correct?  Asking somebody to produce code for you and then explain it to you is not how this site works and will not be well received by many others.

Comment: @Shaggy125 What happens if I remove the code " status.count ne 0 "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there, but I'm not sure what you are doing with the input in your code example.  To get the table to only display 3 columns you could use the [varStatus](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/jstl/core/LoopTagStatus.html) tag loop operator.  The documentation shoes what methods are associated with it.

```
<c:set var="numCols" value="3"/>
<c:set var="numRows" value="3"/>
<c:set var="rowCount" value="0"/>
<table>
    <tr>
        // Loop through each element in the dataList and assign it to a variable named info
        <c:forEach items="${dataList}" var="info" varStatus="status"> 
            // If the current row count is less than the number of row allowed, proceed
            <c:if test="${rowCount lt numRows}">
                // Output the element (info) into a table cell
                <td><input type ="submit" class="data btnColor" value="${info.dataName}" label ="${info.dataId}" /></td>
                // Check to see if the cell that was just created is the 3 one in the row,
                // excluding the very first cell of the table (because 0 % 0 is undefined)
                <c:if test="${status.count ne 0 && status.count % numCols == 0}">
                    // Increment the row count
                    <c:set var="rowCount" value="${rowCount + 1}"/>
                    // End that row and start a new one
                    </tr><tr>
                </c:if>
            </c:if>
        </c:forEach>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Check out [these examples](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm) to learn more about the c:foreach tag.

Comment: Actually the arraylist are series of buttons that is why there is an input type button having its particular value and label. I think the code you presented doesn't met my needs, I already know how to do that. But what i am looking for is, a condition in the foreach loop that will list only 3 rows in the first column and continue the rest in the next column.

Comment: Just modified my answer to include the varStatus.

Comment: The varStatus will let you know what iteration of the loop you are on, starting at 0 (0 based index).  So what I'm saying is if the remainder of the index mod 3 is equal to 0, print out an end of row </tr> and beginning of the next row <tr>.  I will also modify my answer as I just realized I left out a check for the first iteration.

Comment: Did that answer your question?

Comment: Also, how can i set only 3 rows for each column sir? does using <c:set> necessary? please help.

Comment: Add another check to see if the you have iterated 9 times... see my edits.

Comment: Im messed up, i dont understand it clearly can you please apply the <c:if> in the code i had posted? how does the iteration works sir?

Comment: This is beginning to get off topic.  Why don't you update your code with what you have now.  You put the c:if statement in it, try to run it, see what happens.  Have you tried implementing it?  I'm not going to write your code for you, I will however help you with the issues in your code.

Comment: how can I set only 3 rows per column? Are there continuation of values as shown in clarification I posted?

Comment: the table I had shown above in the "To clarify" part .does the code correspond with that? because the 3 rows is not set when i ran the code

Comment: LOOK at your code you have posted.  YOU have NOT implemented anything that has been discussed here.  UPDATE YOUR CODE WITH WHAT YOU NOW HAVE.  The code shown is exactly what was originally posted with the question.  UPDATE IT, or I will not continue trying to help you as you are wasting my time.

Comment: Sir @Shaggy125, can you please add comments on the code depending upon its purpose? thanks